# Displaying PDF on website using pdf.js

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I want to put a file `sample.pdf` on my website, and want it to be displayed using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/). What I want is to display my own file like the [demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), with a toolbar, zooming in/out, etc. So far I can't do that yet.

I did check out the [helloworld example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld), but it simply shows the file like an image, without toolbar, zooming in/out, etc. When I put another file with many pages instead of `helloworld.pdf`, it just shows the first page.

Comment: From my experience, it is a mess. I could not make it work.

Comment: Did you see the "Hello World" example? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld Check the index.html and the hello.js file for an example.

Comment: Yes, I did check that (sorry for not mentioning earlier), but it doesn't show the full pdf.js like in the [demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). When I put another file instead of `helloworld.pdf`, it simply shows the first page of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for but I was able to get this working exactly like the demo.  Although you may not want to use that example viewer for your project, you can use the working code as a starting point for your own requirements.

For a simple test you can just clone the project somewhere under a web server into a directory like myproject and visit http://yourservername.com/myproject/web/viewer.html.  You should see the pdf appear.  This can be a starting point to working with this project.  I did this running a very basic Apache server on Linux.

If you are not looking for an example styled like that the demo above you can also see [this](http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/1/edit) jsbin from the docs that show how to do something completely customized with working next/previous buttons to move between the pages (as you mentioned you were only seeing the first page).

As a note, it seems that this library does not work properly with Safari.  You can see an issue about it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2080).  Unfortunately this makes it unusable for me now as I need to support all current browsers.

Also, remember to watch for the warnings concerning CORS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Snapshot. What I'm looking for is to get this working exactly like the demo. Could you please tell me how you did it?

Comment: Ok never mind, I should have checked the **web** folder. I only checked the **examples** folder.

Comment: FYI: This was fixed in June of 2013. Ref: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/3315

Comment: @SnapShot what was your solution to also support Safari?

Comment: @PaulS. So how *exactly* did you fix the issue with toolbar not appearing?